# Android Mediaplayer: Some (sound) of the audio file remains when it's stopped

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I am using the Android Mediaplayer to play some audio files in a fragment. However, when I stop a certain audio file and then play it again, some of the sound of the last play remains - The part where I stopped it. Why is this happening?

```
public class PageFragment_Bon extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;
    private Button start, stop, replay;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int [] filer = new int[18];


    public static PageFragment_Bon newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment_Bon fragment = new PageFragment_Bon();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
           }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_boenner, container, false);

        start = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);

        stop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);

        replay = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.replay);
        replay.setOnClickListener(this);

        filer[2] = R.raw.takbira;
        filer[4] = R.raw.alfatiha;
        filer[14] = R.raw.tashahhud;
        filer[15] = R.raw.salat;
        filer[16] = R.raw.assalam;

        if(filer[mPage] != 0){
            start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            replay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if(mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(mediaPlayer == null)
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(), filer[mPage]);//add this line

        if(v == start){
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        else if(v == stop){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }

        else if(v == replay){
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if(!isVisibleToUser){

            if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mediaPlayer.reset()` and `mediaPlayer.release()` after calling `mediaPlayer.stop();`

Your code like this,

```
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.release();
```

Comment: In the if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())? Cause that doesn't work. Now I can't play the same sound again

Comment: Then you should use service to play sound.

Comment: Shouldn't I use a service if I want to play the sound in the background? I don't need that